# Round to whole numbers without using conditional statements in Python - Logic

Tags: python, logic, rounding

I'm taking a Python course at Udacity, and I'm trying to work this out for myself without looking at the answer. Perhaps you can give me a hint for my logic?

Below are the instructions and what I have so far. We haven't learned conditional statements yet, so I can't use those. We've only learned how to assign/print a variable, strings, indexing strings, sub-sequences, and .find. They just introduced the str command in this final exercise.

```
# Given a variable, x, that stores the 
# value of any decimal number, write Python 
# code that prints out the nearest whole 
# number to x.
# If x is exactly half way between two 
# whole numbers, round up, so
# 3.5 rounds to 4 and 2.5 rounds to 3.
# You may assume x is not negative.

# Hint: The str function can convert any number into a string.
# eg str(89) converts the number 89 to the string '89'

# Along with the str function, this problem can be solved 
# using just the information introduced in unit 1.

# x = 3.14159 
# >>> 3 (not 3.0)
# x = 27.63 
# >>> 28 (not 28.0)
# x = 3.5 
# >>> 4 (not 4.0)

x = 3.54159

#ENTER CODE BELOW HERE

x = str(x)
dec = x.find('.')
tenth = dec + 1

print x[0:dec]
```

////

So this gets me to print the characters up to the decimal point, but I can't figure out how to have the computer check whether "tenth" is > 4 or < 5 *and* print out something according to the answer.

I figured I could probably get far enough for it to return a -1 if "tenth" wasn't > 4, but I don't know how I can get it to print x[0:dec] *if* it's < 5 and x[0:dec]+1 if it's > 4.

:/

Could someone please give me a nudge in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a weird restriction, but you could do this:

```
x = str(x)
dec_index = x.find('.')
tenth_index = dec_index + 1
tenth_place = x[tenth_index] # will be a string of length 1
should_round_up = 5 + tenth_place.find('5') + tenth_place.find('6') + tenth_place.find('7') + tenth_place.find('8') + tenth_place.find('9')

print int(x[0:dec_index]) + should_round_up
```

What we do is look at the tenths place. Since `.find()` returns -1 if the argument isn't found, the sum of the `.find()` calls will be -4 if if the tenths place is 5, 6, 7, 8, or 9 (since one of the `.find()` calls will succeed and return `0`), but will be -5 if the tenths place is 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4. We add 5 to that, so that `should_round_up` equals 1 if we should round up, and 0 otherwise. Add that to the whole number part, and we're done.

---

That said, if you weren't subject to this artificial restriction, you would do:

```
print round(x)
```

And move on with your life.

Comment: AH! I figured it was something like this, but I still couldn't work out how to execute it.

Agreed. Weird restriction. I guess they're trying to get us to use a certain method of logic.

Comment: Although, I just realized, we haven't learned int yet either. So strange. Thank you so much for your help. I'll see what their answer is and post it here.

Comment: OMG. It was too simple! o.O

We had to add 0.5 to the number which would push it over when we printed to the decimal. 

   `x = 3.14159

    #ENTER CODE BELOW HERE
    x = x + 0.5
x = str(x)
dec = x.find('.')

print x[:dec]`

Comment: Oh. Yeah, that's pretty obviously a better approach than this one.

Answer (score 1):

judging by the accepted answer you only expects floats so that is pretty trivial to solve:

```
x = 3.54159  
# split on .
a, b = str(x).split(".")
# cast left side to int and add result of test for right side being greater or equal to 5
print(int(a) + (int(b) >= 5))
```

`(int(b) > 5)` will be either 1 or 0 i.e `True/False` so we either add 1 when right side is > .5 or flooring when it's < .5 and adding 0.

If you were doing it mathematically you just need to `print(int(x+.5))`, anything >= .5 will mean x will be rounded up and floored when it is < .5.

Comment: OP clearly says that he isn't supposed to use conditional statements.

Comment: Exactly...if we could use if/else statements, but it's a restriction. Thank you for helping. I look forward to if/else!

Answer (score 1):

```
x = 3.54159  
# split on .
a, b = str(x).split(".")
# cast left side to int and add result of test for right side being greater or equal to 5
print(int(a) + (int(b[0]) >= 5))

# above code will not work with 3.14567 and the number with having two or more digits after decimal
```

Comment: above code will not work with 3.14567 and the number with having two or more digits after decimal

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This was an attempt to comment on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28400554/round-to-whole-numbers-without-using-conditional-statements-in-python-logic/28400611#28400611). Please do not post comments as answers. You will be able to post comments once you have earned 50 points here.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's easier...

```
x = x + 0.5
intPart, decPart = str(x).split(".")
print intPart
```

Examples:

- If x = 1, then it will become 1.5 and intPart will be 1.
- If x = 1.1, then it will become 1.6 and intPart will be 1.
- If x = 1.6, then it will become 2.1 and intPart will be 2.

Note: it will only work for positive numbers.

Comment: Clever solution, if possible extend it to work for negative numbers as well :)

Answer (score 1):

## This code will round numbers to the nearest whole

## without using conditionals

You can do it this way

```
x = 3.54159

x = x + 0.5       # This automatically takes care of the rounding

str_x = str(x)    # Converting number x to string 

dp = str_x.find('.')    # Finding decimal point index

print str_x[:dp]        # Printing upto but excluding decimal point
```

Comment: If you like you can convert the string back to integer for future calculations using `int(str_x[:dp])`

Answer (score 0):

I did the same course at Udacity. solved it using the following code:

```
y = str(x)
decimal = y.find('.')
y_increment = y[decimal+1:]
print decimal
print y_increment

# Section below finds >5
check5 = y_increment.find('5',0,1)
check6 = y_increment.find('6',0,1)
check7 = y_increment.find('7',0,1)
check8 = y_increment.find('8',0,1)
check9 = y_increment.find('9',0,1)
yes_increment = (check5 + 1) + (check6 + 1) + (check7 + 1) + (check8 + 1) + (check9 + 1)
print check5, check6, check7, check8, check9

#Calculate rounding up
z = x + (yes_increment)

z = str(z)
final_decimal = z.find('.')
print z[:final_decimal]
```